# System.Collections.Stack.Peek() vs FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I have seen a colleague use `FirstOrDefault()` when interacting with a Stack instead of `Peek()`.

It had never crossed my mind to use an extension method instead of the built-in `Peek()`, and I'm wondering what are the implications / differences between the two.

Is one recommended over the other ? Looking with ildasm.exe didn't teach me anything useful.

Comment: @Servy Instead of berating the guy, why don't you explain why he's wrong?

Comment: @dtsg What's there to explain.  It'll be the exact opposite of what he said.  It won't pop the element off of the stack.  It'll function (basically) identically to calling `Peek`, just as the OP here seems to think.  Why *would* `FirstOrDefault` pop the value off of the stack?

Comment: The obvious difference would be the behavior when given an empty stack.

Comment: @EricJ. Most LINQ operations on `IEnumerable`s have no side effects. This is no different. A stack implements a strategy for enumerating its members, and `FirstOrDefault` just traverses the first element in this enumeration.

Comment: @Asad That's not a function of the LINQ operation (in this case, `FirstOrDefault`).  It's determined by the `IEnumerable` implementation of the stack.  If the stack's `IEnumerable` implementation popped off the items while yielding them, then it would have those semantics.  Of course, the `IEnumerator` implementation of `Stack` *doesn't* do that.  It just yields the items without mutating the stack.  You could write one that would though, if you were so inclined.

Comment: @Servy I guess that's also true, but I would take that to be axiomatic. I've never heard of an IEnumerable that transforms the underlying data when you iterate it.

Comment: @Asad `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable` is the first one that comes to mind.  It's actually a rather effective pattern, so long as you make it clear what its semantics are (`GetConsumingEnumerable` does this in my opinion).

Comment: @Servy Shows how much I know. I'd bet you could have all kinds of fun passing that to an unsuspecting `IEnumerable` consumer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` will return the default value for `T` if the stack is empty; `Peek` will throw.

That's about it as far as functional changes.  `FirstOrDefault` adds a few layers of indirection, creating an enumerable/enumerator object (which will eventually need to be disposed of), computing whether there are more items, fetching the first item through the enumerable, and then returning it, rather than having the stack itself do only the necessary operations.  While this is technically more work, it's highly unlikely for that to be enough to matter in the vast majority of situations.

Answer (score 2):

To quote from MSDn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.peek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Firstly

Peek() is an O(1) operation

FirstOrDefault() works as follows according to Reflector and  is a more expensive operation.

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
   if (source == null)
{
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
}
IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
if (list != null)
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        return list[0];
    }
}
else
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
return default(TSource);
}
```

Secondly,

Peek errors out at an empty stack, FirstOrDefault returns a null value though First() would also error out.

Comment: How does this answer his question about what the differences are?

Comment: Edited to make the differences  more clear. Computationally and Functionally